# WSDL generated SOAPClient invalid SOAP 1.1 Message

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a WebService client that has been created from SOAP 1.2 WSDL file. When I call a method in client, it creates SOAP 1.2 message (I can see it and I add timestamp in handler), but I get

```
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:75)
```

Created SOAPMessage sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" S:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-B02FCFB46EE225EA3214213243149751">gfdgdfgdfzx</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-3">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="S"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse S"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>Cadsad</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-2">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>Q0ZZurxhe0OjNOMzI7jziQ1K5Cbmue9U6L+fjGKG2aE=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>adasdsadsad==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-B02FCFB46EE225EA3214213243149772">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-B02FCFB46EE225EA3214213243149803">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-B02FCFB46EE225EA3214213243149751" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
                <wsu:Created>2015-01-15T12:18:32.998Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-02-14T12:18:32.998Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2">
        <ns2:sendDocumentFile xmlns:ns2="http://asd.webservice.com/">
            <Attachment>
                <fileName>adsad</fileName>
            </Attachment>
        </ns2:sendDocumentFile>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

WSDL file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.df.com/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="WSService" targetNamespace="http://webservice.df.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.df.com/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webservice.df.com/">
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"/>
            <xs:element name="getBatchStatus" type="tns:getBatchStatus"/>
            <xs:element name="getBatchStatusResponse" type="tns:getBatchStatusResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="receiveDocumentFile" type="tns:receiveDocumentFile"/>
            <xs:element name="receiveDocumentFileResponse" type="tns:receiveDocumentFileResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="sendDocumentFile" type="tns:sendDocumentFile"/>
            <xs:element name="sendDocumentFileResponse" type="tns:sendDocumentFileResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="sendDocumentFile">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Attachment" type="tns:attachment"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="attachment">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="fileName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="binaryData" type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sendDocumentFileResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="getBatchStatus">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="packID" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="getBatchStatusResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:cond"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="cond">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="condDesc" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="condKodu" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="packIdentifier" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="receiveDocumentFile">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PaketID" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="receiveDocumentFileResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:attachment"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="WSFault" type="tns:WSFault"/>
            <xs:complexType name="WSFault">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="code" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>  
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getBatchStatusResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getBatchStatusResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sendDocumentFile">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sendDocumentFile" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sendDocumentFileResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:sendDocumentFileResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="WSFault">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:WSFault" name="WSFault">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getBatchStatus">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getBatchStatus" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="receiveDocumentFileResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:receiveDocumentFileResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="receiveDocumentFile">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:receiveDocumentFile" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="WS">
        <wsdl:operation name="sendDocumentFile">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:sendDocumentFile" name="sendDocumentFile">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sendDocumentFileResponse" name="sendDocumentFileResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:WSFault" name="WSFault">
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getBatchStatus">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getBatchStatus" name="getBatchStatus">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getBatchStatusResponse" name="getBatchStatusResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:WSFault" name="WSFault">
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="receiveDocumentFile">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:receiveDocumentFile" name="receiveDocumentFile">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:receiveDocumentFileResponse" name="receiveDocumentFileResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:WSFault" name="WSFault">
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WSServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:WS">
        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="sendDocumentFile">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:SendDocumentFile" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="sendDocumentFile">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="sendDocumentFileResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="WSFault">
                <soap12:fault name="WSFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getBatchStatus">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:GetBatchStatus" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="getBatchStatus">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getBatchStatusResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="WSFault">
                <soap12:fault name="WSFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="receiveDocumentFile">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:ReceiveDocumentFile" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="receiveDocumentFile">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="receiveDocumentFileResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="WSFault">
                <soap12:fault name="WSFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="WSService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:WSServiceSoapBinding" name="WSPort">
            <soap12:address location="https://apptest.df.com/df/services/WSPort"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Did you check the namespace in your WSDL to make sure it is SOAP 1.1 and not something else, like SOAP 1.2?

Comment: Can you please post your WSDL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just solved the problem with changing system configurations.
I put these property values in code and the problem  gone away.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory""com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext", "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory");
```